# ¿Cómo utilizar la función rasterize?

Tags: r

Soy muy nuevo en el mundo de R y espero que puedan ayudarme con este paso...que estoy bien atascado.

Tengo una tabla que incluye las coordenadas de los puntos de muestreo (n=6905) y un índice de calidad de agua. Estoy intentado crear un raster de esta tabla mediante la función rasterize. La función es la siguiente:

`rasterize(x, raster, field, fun=mean, backgroud=0, update=TRUE)`

**x=** Tabla de coordenadas

**raster=** creado con los datos de extensión, nrows, ncol y demás de un raster de referencia.

**field=** un vector creado con los valores del índice de calidad de agua. Cada valor correspondiente a un punto de muestreo.

**fun=mean=** La media de los puntos que coinciden en una cuadrícula del raster

**background=0** para completar las celdas que no tienen ningún valor de field

**update=TRUE** para que los valores de field se actualicen con los del vector.

Al correr esto me devuelve un mapa en blanco y el siguiente resumen (en otro intento eran todo NA´s y en otro 2´s en lugar de 5´s...)

```
Min.            5
1st Qu.         5
Median          5
3rd Qu.         5
Max.            5
NA's    215695154
```

¿Creo que quizás el problema está en la función? He probado a usar el argumento na.rm de la siguiente forma y me sigue pasando lo mismo.

```
na.rm=mean(na.omit(v))
raster.wq=rasterize(xy, raster, v, fun=function(v,na.rm)mean(v), backgroud=0, update=TRUE)
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.
Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido Luis a la comunidad. Es muy probable que el problema tenga que ver con los datos, te sugiero que agregues un muestra de ejemplo del vector `field`, y un `summary` del mismo.

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho!

Adjunto una muestra y un resumen de la columna a usar como `field` y del vector creado:

`wq$QE

   [1] 2.000 3.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 3.267 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000

summary(wq$QE)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   2.633   2.686   3.000   5.000

v=as.vector(wq$QE)
v

[1] 2.000 3.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 2.000 3.267 1.000 1.000 1.000 1.000
summary (v)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   2.633   2.686   3.000   5.000`

Comment: Ok, y el vector `v`, ¿tiene la misma cantidad de elementos que `xy`?

Comment: Sí, ambos tienen 6095 casos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho alguna idea?? He buscando por todos lados y escrito en varios foros y nadie sabe decirme dónde puede estar el fallo... Gracias!

Comment: No es algo que haga habitualmente, por lo que sin ver los datos y más particularmente sin contar con un [mcve]  se me hace difícil ayudarte. ¿Como estás construyendo `raster`? ¿que datos tiene?